# When I convert NSString to JSON, I get null

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsstring

I am doing some webscraping and am able to get the html source code off of my desired page, but I am casting it to a NSString. When I try to convert that to JSON, I get a null when I try to print it. When I print responseString2 I am seeing the source code, but as an NSString. What am I doing wrong?

```
let task2 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request2 as URLRequest) { data2, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data2 != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error2=\(error)")
                return
            }
            
            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse , httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode2 should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response2 = \(response)")
            }
            
            let responseString2 = NSString(data: data2!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            
            print("hthpage \(responseString2)")
            if let dataFromString = responseString2?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue, allowLossyConversion: false){
                let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
                print("JASON \(json)")
            }
```

Comment: Check what the output of responseString2.data is. Is it giving any value or is it null?

Comment: @Ajil O. It gives me the source code of the website I am trying to get data off of.

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert data->string->data.

Try this code

and check the error if the error occurred when converting data to json.

```
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request!) { (d, response, error) in

        if let data = d
        {
            if let str = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            {
                print("data->string : " + str)
            }

            do
            {
                if let obj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        complete(obj)
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    print("Http - JsonSerialization Failed, not String:AnyObject Type!!")
                }
            }
            catch let err as NSError
            {
                print("Http - JsonSerialization Error")
                print(err)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if error != nil
            {
                print("Http - URLSession.shared.dataTask Error")
                print(error)
            }
        }
        }.resume()
```

Comment: What is `complete(obj)`?

Comment: Also, I get this error `Http - JsonSerialization Error
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}`

Comment: complete() is my callback parameter. :)

Comment: ok. the response text is not json form. so this error occurred. can you show me the responseString?

Comment: I changed my code. can you tell me the log? that 'data->string' part?

Comment: I found the issue, it returns the html format of the page. Any idea on how to convert it to json?